# How much energy is lost by a capacitor regulating a voltage regulator? If you increase the size of the capacitor, how does this change?

Tags: capacitor, energy

An ideal capacitor loses no energy while regulating the voltage provided by a DC regulator, if the regulator keeps up. No capacitor is this ideal.

In the real world, the capacitor will lose voltage as it self-discharges... and is re-charged by the voltage regulator. What is the scale of this energy loss? If I double the capacitor, how does that impact the energy loss?

If it matters, the regulator I care about is a CP1700-3302E/TO.

Comment: Why they downvoted the question? it's the essence of ESR and dissipation factor of a capacitor!

Comment: I wish I knew?  I'm mostly assuming that it's a 'everyone knows that's not important' thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The energy that moves in and out of the capacitor is not lost, it simply is stored and retrieved.

There is a (typically small) amount of energy lost in leakage and a (typically larger) amount of energy lost in the ESR of the capacitor (I^2*R).

The first amount can be approximated by a leakage current multiplied by the average voltage across the capacitor. The latter depends on the RMS current the capacitor experiences and the ESR value. You should be able to find values, or at least limits to the values, in the datasheet, but the RMS current is a characteristic of your circuit.

The MCP1700 is a linear low-Iq regulator. The value of the capacitor won’t directly affect losses much, but if your source is AC, doubling it would reduce the ripple, this increasing the average voltage into the regulator and increasing losses (in the regulator, not the capacitor) that way (but yielding more headroom for the regulator and more tolerance to capacitor aging etc.)

Comment: Power source is battery; objective is very long run time on a single set.  Currently at ~4 months.

Comment: The capacitor value will have little effect. Leakage may have a slight effect depending on the specifics, but maybe hardly measurable under typical conditions.

Comment: He didn't actually say if it's a linear or switching regulator. ESR in a switcher is a major loss, leakage is usually negligible unless you are using a *huge* electrolytic (then it would be on the order of some mA)

Comment: I think the regulator Iinear low-Iq type, from the part number given and how that matches up to parts sold.

Comment: This is a linear regulator, but if the regulator types have significantly different behaviours, I'd love more detail.

Answer (score 3):

The loss here is negligible.

There are other places where energy is lost, the most egregious one being linear regulators that convert excess voltage to heat, as they act like a variable resistor. This one is a massive waste, but might be worth it depending on the application.

Smaller effects are:

- a switching regulator requires an oscillator, and the switching FET will also warm up because it doesn't switch instantly, but goes through a period where it acts as a resistor
- badly regulated voltages contain high-frequency noise that is also radiated away
- repeatedly charging and discharging a capacitor also introduces resistive losses

These effects are very small already, but likely still larger or in the same order of magnitude as capacitor self-discharge.

Unless you are building a microampere application, you can likely ignore these terms.

For microamperes, a lot of what is "good regulator design" for normal applications goes out of the window -- suddenly linear regulators make sense again because even a large voltage times a small current is a small amount of power.

Comment: OVerall project is very low power.  Previous itterations have run on 4 AAs for ~4 months.  Core purpose of this question is to determine if the capacitor is worth worrying about.